# Wysiwyg - uploading images to amazon

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, wysiwyg

I need a wysiwyg that can handle uploading images to Amazon S3...Is there something like that? Right now I'm trying to configure TinyMCE to do that, but I'm not able to handle the upload to amazon itself.

I am actually using the bundle and a custom service to handle the upload. And it usually is performed in controllers.

So I don't know what would be the logic here...

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried redactor (http://imperavi.com/redactor/). It should have a plugin that allows you to upload to amazon.

Answer (score 0):

I am using OneUpUploaderBundle, which can attach to various file upload mechanisms:

https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle